# Read DynamicMethod's LocalSignature: non standard type tokens?

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit

I recently started using ILVisualizer in VS2010 to inspect the IL for dynamic methods. However it does not extract LocalVariable infos from the IL stream, so I'm giving it a try (for the fun of it, of course, and because it's a good learning experience :)

For statically compiled methods, that's not an issue, since we can access the method's body through GetMethodBody() and get the local variables from there.

With DynamicMethods however, the method body is not available through GetMethodBody(). I found a workaround, which gets me the local signature as a byte array, and from there I can extract the count, type, and index of the method's locals, according to the CIL spec. All is well as long as we're dealing with native types (short, byte, string...).

But if a local variable is a class type, it gets referenced with the ELEMENT_TYPE_INTERNAL (0x21) flag, instead of ELEMENT_TYPE_CLASS within the local signature.

Unfortunately, I can't find anything on how to read a type stored as ELEMENT_TYPE_INTERNAL. 
What's up with that ? Does MS use non-standard CIL for dynamic methods ? Anyone know of a way to read properly those signatures ?

**Edit** I stumbled across some source files for mscorlib.dll, and found from SignatureHelper's source that this possibly happens when the class is a runtime type. I'll investigate into that...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I believe I got it !

It turns out that data after the ELEMENT_TYPE_INTERNAL flag is not compressed data, it is a plain 32-bit integer (or 64, depending on the platform, though I have to confirm that) stored on 4 bytes, which is the pointer to the referenced type.

Even though I couldn't find a way to get a RuntimeTypeHandle from an IntPtr, looping through the tokens in the method's DynamicScope object and comparing values works to get the type handle.